# JS. Непонятное формирование объектов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему в `items` передаются последние значения. А логи выглядят так: заголовки как надо, а содержание такое?

```
  for (i = 0; i < listCount; i++) {
    itemsArr.product_id = nidsArr[i];
    itemsArr.qnt = amountArr[i];
    itemsArr.price = priceArr[i];

    console.log(itemsArr);
    items[i] = itemsArr;       
  }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем отличие от предыдущего вопроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < listCount; i++) {

    items.push({
        product_id: nidsArr[i],
        qnt: amountArr[i],
        price: priceArr[i]
    });       
  }
```